# Jssor image change linked to dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, jssor

I'm using Jssor Slider to display product images on one of my sites. I'm using the slider with thumbnail navigation and for most products the standard implementation works perfectly as standard. However, there are a number of products for which the various options are chosen from a drop-down list (each of which has it's own specific image). To load all the thumbnails I just loop through the database table and I do the same to populate the drop-down list.

What I would like to do is for the selection of a specific drop-down option to trigger the same action as clicking on the relevant thumbnail and to load the full size image.

Before I added the jssor slider to the product page I had just used JavaScript to get the selected index and change the main image source that way:

http://www.scotcrest.com/singleproduct.php?action=More+Details&productId=18&productName=Clan%20Cloot%20Tea%20Towels

(That's the current version - without jssor)

but I'm not really that experienced with jquery (I'm usually working with php) so I'm at a loss as to how to work this in with the jssor functions.

I've tried to do this by looking at the code that is triggered on clicking on a thumbnail and trying to get that to fire on changing the select box but didn't really get anywhere.

This is the new version I'm working on but can't get the drop-down to trigger the image change:

http://www.scotcrest.com/singleproduct2.php?action=More+Details&productId=18&productName=Clan%20Cloot%20Tea%20Towels

Could anybody help point me in the right direction as to where to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the shadowbox opening code to your `changeimage` function should work:

```
function changeimage(x){
    var s = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
    document.getElementById("mainproductpic").src = s.getAttribute("data-value1");
    document.getElementById('ThumbImageOne').href = s.getAttribute("data-value1");
    mynum = s.getAttribute("data-value2");
    Shadowbox.open(document.getElementById('ThumbImageOne'));
    Shadowbox.change(mynum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think I should have added the link for the new version of the product page that I'm working with. The link I gave was for the current one that is working to show what I wanted to achieve with jssor on the new one. I'll edit my question with the new link as well. Sorry for being so confusing!